# Ratio of areas in triangles with Cevians

Tags: geometry, triangles, area, ratio

Can someone show me how to solve this problem as they normally would? It would also be very helpful if you could also give me a mass points solution. I know mass points works for ratios of segments, but I do not know how to use them for areas.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am adding a drawing here:

[image]

Triangle ABC area A

2(X+V)=Y+U=2/3A, X+Y=V+U=1/2A

May be this helps...